# How enable google managed certificate on Google Kubernetes?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, certificate, ssl-certificate, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

I'm new to GKE now am trying to creating a new cluster for RASA. I'm trying to create an ingress with HTTPS to point to a loadbalancer in this cluster. But I'm unable to select the option `Create Google-managed certificate` from the list. It seems to be disabled in this cluster. How enable this?

The help shows:

> To create Google-managed certificates, your cluster needs to have
> `ManagedCertificate` Custom Resource Definition present.

[image]

Comment: Did you follow this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs)?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yes I tried that way , In that we need to create yaml manually, But the GUI way is pretty much better for me. (Previously worked for me once but don't know How its enabled).

Comment: how add ManagedCertificate Custom Resource Definition ?

Comment: Ok, you want to add it by GUI, right? Not by using kubectl CLI, don't you?

Comment: Currently am added the certificate as in the documentation, but not sure how enable this option.

Comment: Please provide information how you created this cluster and what configuration did you applied. Also your Ingress YAML configuration.

Comment: am trying to build RASA-X using https://github.com/rasahq/rasa-x-helm

Comment: @PRAJINPRAKASH As I mention in my answer, to use this option in GKE UI must be in `NodePort` service type. Im not able to verify what you have in `certificate.yaml`. If you would change service type from `ClusterIP` to `NodePort` this option is visible. Did you to change this service type?

Comment: @PRAJIN PRAKASH, have you managed to solve this problem ? Did you follow the recommendations provided by PjoterS in his answer ?

Comment: yes @mario use this for manually create certificate kubectl create -f abc-cert.yaml

Answer (score 3):

Posting this community wiki answer to give more visibility on recently fixed issue of grayed out option to create `Create a Google-managed certificate`.

Feel free to edit and expand.

---

You can find the corresponding *Issue* on the GCP Issuetracker:

- *[Issuetracker.google.com: Issues: Creation of Managed Certificate in GCP Cloud Console (Web UI) is grayed out](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/188887367)*

Citing the part of the message from the thread:

> As I can see, this issue was already fixed. You shouldn't encounter it anymore.

---

#### Example

As stated above, this issue shouldn't show up anymore. After reproduction with the following steps:

- Create a `GKE` cluster and wait for it's provisioning.
- Create a sample workload and expose it with:

  - `$ kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx`
  - `$ kubectl expose deployment nginx --port=80 --type=NodePort`
- Go to:

  - `Cloud Console` -> `Kubernetes Engine` -> `Services & Ingress` -> `Create Ingress` (after choosing nginx `Service)` -> `Frontend configuration` -> `HTTPS` -> `Create a new certificate`

The following option can be seen as available:

[image: GOOGLE-MANAGED-CERT]

---

Additional resources:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Docs: How to: Managed certs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs)*

Answer (score -1):

As you didn't provide the steps you're following, I will demonstrate how to do it the right way.

First of all, if you check [Setting up HTTP(S) Load Balancing with Ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer), you will find information thate GKE integrated support for two types of Cloud Load Balancing:

> When you specify `type:LoadBalancer` in the resource manifest, GKE creates a `Service` of type `LoadBalancer`.
>
> When you specify `type:Ingress` in the resource manifest, you instruct GKE to create an `Ingress` resource. By including annotations and supporting workloads and Services, you can create a custom `Ingress controller`.
> ...
> The load balancer's URL map's host rules and path matchers reference one or more backend services, where each backend service corresponds to a GKE Service of type NodePort, as referenced in the Ingress

In another part of the GKE Documentation, related to [Using Google-managed SSL certificates](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs#gcloud), you can find two important notes:

> This feature is only available with Ingress for External HTTP(S) Load Balancing.

> Managed Certificates is a Beta feature available in all GKE versions. In clusters with masters running Kubernetes lower than 1.16.5-gke.1 Managed Certificates are available in version v1beta1, and they do not support multiple subject alternative names (SANs) per certificate.
>
> In GKE 1.16.5-gke.1 and higher Managed Certificates are available in version v1beta2 and they support up to 100 SANs per certificate, version v1beta1 is also still available.

I have tested a few scenarios including `LoadBalancer` and `NodePort` as service type. In RASA-X chart, the service is of a `LoadBalancer` type.
In all my tests when I wanted to `Create Google Managed Certificate`, it worked only with `NodePort`.

Did you try to edit this service and change it to `NodePort`?

A good example to check is to follow [this tutorial](https://medium.com/searce/using-multiple-google-managed-certificate-with-single-kubernetes-ingress-29c78ca4a013).

If you still experience the same issue, please provide more information about your environment and steps to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer,I already done this by creating certificate through thecommand `kubectl apply -f certificate.yaml `, but just want to know why `Create Google-managed certificate` button still disabled.

Comment: Did you change anything after deploying the chart?